# Advantage database how to retieve connection name

Tags: triggers, connection, advantage-database-server

I am using Sybase Advantage, I have 2 tables:

- The first table has the data records
- The second table stores a history of the first

The first table has triggers to populate records in the second table depending on which fields get changed.

I would like to store the connection name (PC which made the request), the name that is displayed in the active queries page (Server Info dialog) and not the username. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803747/how-to-define-a-current-user

Answer (score 2):

The following SQL statement can be used to retrieve the computer name instead of the user name.

`SELECT * 
   FROM 
      ( EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_mgGetConnectedUsers() ) ConnUsers 
   WHERE 
      ConnUsers.DictionaryUser = USER();`

The stored procedure sp_mgGetConnectedUsers is documented [here](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?master_sp_mggetconnectedusers.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this query does not work, I am using Advantage version 9. The Execute procedure returns info in connected users but the query returns a missing table error. Also this does not work if multiple users have the same connection details. I could do with knowing which OSUserLoginName is using a trigger (updating a table).

Comment: If your dictionary logins are not unique, then things get a bit more complicated.  Your best bet is to set the Application ID to contain a unique GUID Identifying the string and then searching on that.

Comment: We are using version 9 which does not have the ApplicationID property in the connection component. I don't know how this would work either when in a trigger. I was thinking that instead of including it in the trigger to add a record to a history table (after trigger), there could be another trigger type before that updates a field in the table with the user, then after the second trigger can pickup this value.

Comment: You can always call sp_SetApplicationID to set the Application ID.  My personal favorite is EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_SetApplicationID( NEWIDSTRING( N ) + ' ' + APPLICATIONID() );  You still have the application ID listing the executable name, but there is a now a GUID for connection.

Comment: That works great, added a new stored procedure which is set from the user logging it at the client end, this changes the applicationID, then I retrieve the applicationID in the trigger. Thanks